# On a Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

Here is the Question I'm stuck on:

A petrol station has service areas on both sides of a motorway, one to serve north-bound traffic and the other for south-bound trafﬁc. The number of north— bound vehicles arriving at the station in one minute has a Poisson distribution with mean **1.4**, and the number of south-bound vehicles arriving in one minute has a Poisson distribution with mean **2.3** the two distributions being independent.

(i) Find the probability that in a one-minute period 
(a)exactly three vehicles arrives
(b) more than four vehicles arrive at this petrol station
giving your answers correct to three places of decimals.

**Given that in a particular one-minute period five Vehicles arrive, find:**

**(ii) the probability that they are all from the same direction**

**(iii) the most likely combination of north-bound and south-bound**

I've completed part i, but don't know how to solve ii and iii. The answers should be: ii. 0.454, and iii. 2 northbound, 3 southbound. Could someone answer this with an explained solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your answers.

Recall the Poisson distribution is:

$$P(k) = e^{-\mu} {\mu^k \over k!}.$$

Here $\mu_1 = 1.4$ and $\mu_2 = 2.3$.

I find:

(i):  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^3 P_1(k) P_2(3-k) = 0.20872.$

(ii):  $1 - \sum\limits_{k=0}^4 \left( P_1(k) \sum\limits_{j=0}^{4-k} P_2(j) \right) = 0.312781.$

For part 2 i:  Calculate the probability of:  $(n_1 = 5 \wedge n_2 = 0) \vee (n_1 = 0 \wedge n_2 = 5)$.  I find:  $0.0143688$.

For part 2 ii:  Calculate the $(n_1 = i \wedge n_2 = 5-i)$ for $0 \leq i \leq 5$ and select the maximizing case (indeed $n_1 = 2 \wedge n_2 = 3$, which has overall probability $0.0491325$).